# Node.js, Visual Studio Code, how to get intellisense for custom methods in project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a project written in Node.js, and I have created a number of methods which I have in a commons.js file, which I would like to be included in intellisense.  Is this possible?  How could I do this?  Just to be clear these are methods I wrote myself, and access in the project by requiring the commons.js file.  I can provide any additional info as needed, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellisense with third party JavaScript libraries in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956904/intellisense-with-third-party-javascript-libraries-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I'll try the idea of creating a tsd.d.ts file, not sure I understand the answer there though, what is a d.ts file reference?  Isn't that typescript?  John Papa also suggests using a "tsconfig.json with no files (leave it undefined)."  I'm assuming that should be in the root of the project?  I'll be amazed if that works but I'll try it... in my case it's not a library I've imported, but rather methods I've written myself and defined in the commons.js file.

Comment: Read online what typings files are about, but yes they are written in Typescript to give vscode type information for JS code. This includes even descriptions (if written as JavaDoc comments). Vscode reads those files and uses them for completion items when it can match any to the current caret position.